# Self-hosted web IDE for web development

Tags: linux, web-apps, web-development, ide, self-hosted

**Goal:** Develop my application in my own Linux server, through a self-hosted IDE.

**Requirements:**

- Open-source
- Compatible with Linux servers
- SSH **Bash**-like terminal (autocomplete it's the most important feature in terminal)
- (Just to mention) Access it via a browser and/or application
- To develop applications based solely in web technologies: **JavaScript, NodeJS, PHP, HTML, CSS**

**Optional plus features:**

- Simple to install and configure
- GitHub integration
- Collaborative editing
- Sublime Text key bindings (or option to customize key bindings)

**What I already know:**

1. **[Codebox](https://www.codebox.io/)** : Meets all requirements, but it's frozen since Corvisa's acquisition
2. **[Codiad](http://codiad.com/)** : Extremely simple, but collab. editing doesn't work anymore, it lacks sublime key bindings and development is almost frozen
3. **[cloud9 (v2)](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9)** / **[c9 (v3)](https://github.com/c9/core/)** : Respectively [discontinued](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) (v2) and [not fully open source anymore](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/v0.1/docs/the-licenses-for-cloud9-sdk-and-packages) (v3).
4. **[Eclipse Orion](https://orionhub.org)** : (please add details here, since there is almost no one in official website)
5. **[Eclispe Che](https://eclipse.org/che/)** : (edited) It is online again and it is a possible candidate. Answer for it, if you want :)

Comment: Just to let you know, Eclipse Che has moved to https://eclipse.org/che/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theia**

Theia meets exactly all the mentioned requirements and much more.

You can run it on desktop **and on cloud** and it's open source. Incredible project!

https://www.theia-ide.org/

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Che is online again and is the only known option at the moment.

https://eclipse.org/che/